# Supremum of a uniformly convergent sequence is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ such that $|f_n (x)| \leq 1$
for all n and $x \in  [0, 1]$. If $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly in $[0, 1]$ to a function $f$ , prove
that the function
$$g  (x) = \sup\{f_n (x)\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
is continuous on $[0, 1]$.

---

I prefer hints if it is possible.

Comment: you might prove by induction that $g_N(x) = \sup_{n < N} f_n(x)$ is continuous, then that $g_N(x)$ converges uniformly to $g(x)$, hence it is continuous

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Using uniform convergence $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, and all $x$.

Using the (uniform) continuity of $f$, show that $|f_n(x)-f_m(y)|<\varepsilon$ for sufficiently large $n,m$ and all $x,y$ with (say) $|x-y|<\delta$.

Use this to show continuity of $g$.

Note: The assumption $|f_n(x)|\leq 1$ is redundant, since we have uniform convergence on a compact set.